# Unable to Access CSS Files

Tags: css, go

I'm working on a Go web application where I have the following directory structure:

```
frontend
└── cmd
      ├── main.go
      ├── assets
      │ └── css
      │       └── styles.css
      └── web
          └── templates
              ├── base.layout.gohtml
              └── register.page.gohtml
              └── test.page.gohtml
```

In this structure, my CSS files are located in the frontend/cmd/assets/css directory, and my HTML templates are located in the cmd/web/templates directory.

However, when I try to access my HTML pages in the browser, the CSS files are not being loaded. When I inspect the network requests, I notice that the CSS file requests are returning a 404 error.

Here's an example of how I'm linking the CSS file in my HTML templates:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/css/styles.css">`

I expect this link to correctly load the CSS file from the assets/css directory, but it seems like the server is unable to find the CSS files.

I also initiated a file server in my main.go :

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets"))
http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", fs))
```

First I did not know about starting a static filer server. So I added that and expected that to work then.

Can anyone help me understand why my CSS files are not being loaded and how I can correctly link them to my HTML templates in a Go web application? Thank you!

Comment: Where do you start the server? From the base directory? The `cmd` directory? Also, (relative) http URLs *may* but do not necessarily *have* to correspond to paths. Also, please provide a [mre].